# How to Crawling these script in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

For the very first time, I tried to use BeautifulSoup for crawling HTML.

The part that I wanted to crawl was below the picture(red box).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlJEg.png)

So I make a code to using *request* and *bs*, like this.

```
    response = requests.get(Url_Front+str(url)+Url_End).text
    
    soup = bs(response)

    print(respone)
```

but the result seems like this...

```
<script src="/sijangtong/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sijangtong/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sijangtong/js/jquery/form/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sijangtong/js/jquery/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="/sijangtong/js/jquery/dynatree/jquery.dynatree.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/sijangtong/js/jquery/simplemodal/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.3.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/sijangtong/js/sijang/sijang_comm.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/sijangtong/js/sijang/sijang_util.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Tons of time spending noticed that it has to use 'Selenium'.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs  # HTML parser library
from selenium import webdriver  # web crawling for javascript

for url in Url_Number:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python_Study\chromedriver.exe.')
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    Real_url = Url_Front+str(url)+Url_End
    driver.get(Real_url)
    div_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="onnuriShopPopList"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody')

    for my_div_elements in div_elements:
        print(my_div_elements.get_attribute("table"))
driver.quit()
```

The result seems like this.

> runfile('C:/Users/rlatj/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/rlatj/.spyder-py3')
> None

Actually, I don't know where I have to fix it.

1. Am I having the right concept of HTML and selenium?

> My concept: selenium is able to crawl javascript parser in HTML.

2. Why the result is 'None'?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Copy and pasted the outer HTML from the DOM inspector of the browser.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.